# Gatling - GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: scala, gatling

I am getting the following error when I tried to Initiate my test.
The test includes a large feeder which loops for 620,000 and has a map of 120 items with in the feeder.

```
Uncaught exception when running trip_dte: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
[error] sbt.ForkMain$ForkError: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
[error]     at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap.updated0(HashMap.scala:358)
[error]     at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap.$plus(HashMap.scala:62)
[error]     at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap.$plus(HashMap.scala:36)
[error]     at scala.collection.mutable.MapBuilder.$plus$eq(MapBuilder.scala:29)
[error]     at scala.collection.mutable.MapBuilder.$plus$eq(MapBuilder.scala:25)
[error]     at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$anonfun$$plus$plus$eq$1(Growable.scala:59)
[error]     at scala.collection.generic.Growable$$Lambda$44/1950093417.apply(Unknown Source)
[error]     at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:32)
[error]     at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:29)
[error]     at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:38)
[error]     at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
[error]     at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq$(Growable.scala:50)
[error]     at scala.collection.mutable.MapBuilder.$plus$plus$eq(MapBuilder.scala:25)
[error]     at scala.collection.generic.GenMapFactory.apply(GenMapFactory.scala:48)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't provide enough information to be able to figure out your issue.

Possible issues:

- you're using an eager feeder (large CSV like feeders are lazy in modern Gatling version, but no idea which Gatling version or which kind of feeder you use).
- your system under load or your bandwidth can't handle the load you're trying to generate and your virtual users pile up in memory (can't complete their journey and no virtual users keep on arriving).

Comment: I am using an iterator feeder as below val timeFeeder = (for ( i <- 0 until 620000) yield { Map("timestamp" -> (current +i*1000).toString())}  where map has 120 items in it ("timestamp1"->(current+(i*1000)+1000).toString())......"timestamp120"->(current+(i*1000)+120000).toString())}) . when I use the above feeder for 10 requests it works fine . I have to send 150 requests per second for 1 hour to see the application can handle the load. The requests has to be different each time. If i have a template where the above 120 timestamp are predefined using ELF everything works.

Comment: No, that's not an Iterator. `0 until 620000` is a Range (https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.2/scala/collection/immutable/Range.html) which is a concrete Seq. You whole data stock sits in memory.

Comment: how can I achieve then since I need 120 timestamp with difference of 1 second and this has to be different for each requests so that I can feed this to json template. I tried crafting the json and sending through string body which is also taking time for 150 requests which is been sent simultaneously for 1 hour

Comment: IMHO, what you need is beyond what can be done on SOF. You need some consulting hours with someone working with you understanding your use case and crafting code for you.